# How to convert time offset value to GMTformat in Java

Tags: java, time, calendar, localdatetime

I get from remote API such kind body:

```
    {
       "timezone": "18000",
       "id": "1512569",
       "name": "Tashkent"
    }
```

How can I convert timezone field to GMT format?
For example in my case:

```
timezon:18000  = GMT 5
```

Comment: `ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(18000)`. Yields `+05:00`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert the given number of seconds into a `ZoneOffset` instance and then format it the desired string e.g.

```
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendLiteral("GMT")
                                        .appendOffset("+H:mm", "Z")
                                        .toFormatter(Locale.ROOT);

        ZoneOffset offset = ZoneOffset.ofTotalSeconds(18000);
        String formattedOffset = formatter.format(offset);
        System.out.println(offset);
        System.out.println(formattedOffset);
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
+05:00
GMT+5
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.